# How do I make the map value a constant in function parameter in dart

Tags: flutter, dart

Why does dart complain "The default value of an optional parameter must be constant". How do I make the map value constant

```
Map<String, int> toastDuration = {
  "defaut": 4000,
};

void showToast({
  BuildContext context,
  String msg,
  int msDuration = toastDuration["default"], // Error: The default value of an optional parameter must be constant
  bool hidePrev = true,
}) {
  ....
}
```

I tried adding  const but that didn't work as it expects map part to be a class.

int msDuration = **const** toastDuration["default"],

Comment: Must be `const toastDuration = {
  "defaut": 4000,
};`

Answer (score 2):

toastDuration["default"] can't be constant because it's an expression calculated later (Think about the fact you can put any string in the braces). You can do something similar like that:

```
const defaultToastDuration = 4000;
Map<String, int> toastDuration = {
  "default": defaultToastDuration,
}

void showToast({
  BuildContext context,
  String msg,
  int msDuration = defaultToastDuration,
  bool hidePrev = true,
}) {
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As the error message says `The default value of an optional parameter must be constant`. Think about what happens if you remove the `default` key from `toastDuration`. Instead of using a map here you can simply use the default value directly.

```dart
void showToast({
  BuildContext context,
  String msg,
  int msDuration = 4000,
  bool hidePrev = true,
})
```

Another problem in your original code is that if you change the `default` key to say 300, the `showToast` will break because default parameters must be constants.